# Issue bash script doesnot print time

Tags: bash, shell, unix, parallel-processing, multiprocess

I have following code, two bash scripts running in parallel in main bash script.
I want script to run in parallel and when its finished I need total setup time, but it doesn't show setup time it shows time of scripts file only.

Cloud.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s%3N)
ssh test@192.168.101.238 'docker build -t server .'
end=$(date +%s%3N)
echo "build duration cloud: $((duration=end-start)) ms"
```

client.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s%3N)
sudo docker build -t server .'
end=$(date +%s%3N)
echo "build duration: $((duration=end-start)) ms"
```

Main.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s%3N)
sh ./cloud.sh &
sh ./client.sh &
end=$(date +%s%3N)
echo "Setup time: $((duration=end-start))ms."
```

Thanks help is highly appreciated.

Comment: So `wait` on these scripts to finish.

Comment: The assignment to `duration` in `$((duration=end-start))` is pointless — you don't use `$duration`.  You could write just `$((end-start))`.  However, it doesn't directly explain your problem.  In `client.sh`, you appear to have a stray single quote at the end of the `sudo` line.  If that's real, it might be why things aren't working.

Comment: You're running your sub scripts with `sh`, but they have `bash` shebangs. I don't see any bashisms in them that would break under `sh`, but it's best to be consistent...